# A variant of the minimum vertex cover

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, vertex-cover

In my research I confront a variant of the vertex cover problem as follows:

Given a graph G, a vertex v  and a number k, to decide whether G has a  vertex cover of size k
that contain v.

I have search all over literature and could not find a similar problem. I am interested in the complexity of this problem ( I have proved that it complete for $P^NP[long]$ ).

The question is have you ever seen such variant of vertex cover problem? How do you call this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Given a graph G and a integer `K`, to decide whether G has a vertex cover of size `K` is the decision problem of minimal vertex cover problem. And it is NP-complete.

If fact, the problem you described is no difference with that one. That is because if you have contained vertex v, you can remove v and all edges having v as an end-point. What you should do next is to decide whether you can cover the left sub-graph with `k-1` vertices.